# Render partial not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have rails apps where a user can `like` a `post`, a "like" link will change to "dislike" link (using render partial) when user clicked a "like" link, also it can create one record of `like` and it's works save to database, I can see partial have rendered on logs but partial not displayed on views also a "like" link removed.

```
Started POST "/like" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-01 16:45:48 +0700
  ←[1m←[35mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Processing by HomesController#create_like as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"kRfosGW9Qsv3e8VH8MU/X/EyLVoJ/ya8T3Abwv7qNwg=", "like"=>{"post_id"=>"4"}}
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mBEGIN←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO "likes" ("created_at", "post_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 01 Jul 2014 09:45:48 UTC +00:00], ["post_id", 4], ["updated_at", Tue, 01 Jul 2014 09:45:48 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 1]]
  ←[1m←[36mPost Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = 4 LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  UPDATE "posts" SET "count_like" = COALESCE("count_like", 0) + 1 WHERE "posts"."id" = 4
  ←[1m←[36m (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mCOMMIT←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mPost Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  Rendered homes/_like_dislike.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered homes/create_like.js.erb (6.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 42.0ms (Views: 31.0ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
```

When I tried to reload/refresh browser, "dislike" link is displaying.

And this `_posts.html.erb` file

```
<div class="perpost-content" id="<%= dom_id(post) %>">
    <div class="perpost-body"><p><%= post.body %></p></div>
    <div class="perpost-footer">
        <ul class="inline">
            <li id="like_<%= dom_id(post) %>">
                <%= render 'like_dislike', :post => post %>
            </li>
            <% if post.user_id == current_user.id %><li><%= link_to "delete", destroy_post_path(post), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "yakin akan dihapus?"}, :remote => true %></li><% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

`_like_dislike.html.erb` file

```
<% @base_secure = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 %>
<% if post.liked_by? current_user %>
    <%= link_to "dislike", destroy_like_path(post.likes.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "yakin akan dihapus?"}, :remote => true %>
<% else %>
    <%= form_for Like.new, :url => { :action => "create_like" }, :html => {:id => "send_like_"+ @base_secure}, :remote => true do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => post.id %>
        <%= link_to 'like', "#", :onclick => "$('#send_like_"+ @base_secure +"').submit()" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`create_like.js.erb`

```
$('#like_<%= dom_id(@post) %>').empty().append('<%= j render :partial => "homes/like_dislike", :collection => @post, :as => :post %>');
```

`create_like` action on `homes_controller.rb`

```
def create_like
  @like = Like.new(params[:like])
  @like.user_id = current_user.id
  @like.save
  @post_id = params[:like][:post_id].to_i
  @post = Post.find(@post_id)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
   end  
end
```

Comment: You're rendering it as a collection in `create_like.js` but you only have a single object.  I'm not sure if that's the only issue but that could be part of it.

Comment: @Baloo thanks baloo, I have changed collection to local object look like this `$('#like_<%= dom_id(@post) %>').empty().append('<%= j render :partial => "homes/like_dislike", :locals => {:post => @post } %>');` and it's works

Comment: You say "When I tried to reload/refresh a page, dislike link is displaying."  Does that mean that the partial **is** being shown, but you're seeing the "dislike" link instead of the "like" link from the partial?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I mean when clicked "like" link, "dislike" not displayed from partial, but after that I tried to refresh browser "dislike" link from partial is being shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baloo said "You're rendering it as a collection in `create_like.js` but you only have a single object." So I tried to change this

```
$('#like_<%= dom_id(@post) %>').empty().append('<%= j render :partial => "homes/like_dislike", :collection => @post, :as => :post %>');
```

to

```
$('#like_<%= dom_id(@post) %>').empty().append('<%= j render :partial => "homes/like_dislike", :locals => {:post => @post } %>');
```

[Action View Partials Rails 3.2.18](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.18/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html)